# Internet Explorer not rendering javascript properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I got ran into a small problem but can not figure out why it is happening. On internet explorer 9 and above the following code is rendering as it should be as given below

```
<div class="nav-bar">
```

but in internet explorer 8 its display this

```
<DIV class=nav-bar jQuery18306474608844609571="10">
```

please help and thanks

Comment: Where's the Javascript? What are you expecting as a result? What's wrong going on?

Comment: This is completly normal. jQuery adds this tags to elements you perform acations on it to identify them by an id

Comment: This is a jQuery feature, shouldn't be an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3317101/1414562

Comment: http://www.airmaster.dk/

Comment: in internet explorer 8 the menu bar is not showing up as it should do

Comment: @UmarKhan but i guess this is not the reason. You should check IE8 console for error and ask a new question regarding your issue

Comment: How does this property influence the rendering?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Its how jQuery identify different DOM-notes when you for instance wants to store data on a node:

```
 $(node).data('a', true);
```

Instead of storing the data identifier on the node it sets it as an attribute in IE8 to avoid trouble with the Garbage Collector.

In modern browsers jQuery stores the identifier directly on the node.

Look in the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) under `function internalData( elem, name, data, pvt /* Internal Use Only */ ){`